# jquery ajax with servlet

Tags: jquery, ajax, servlets

I had a problem when using servlet with jquery ajax. When I put the html file which contains the js code in the same project with the servlet, it will work. However, when I used this html on another machine and used the URL:`http://192.168.1.5:8084/****/Servlet` for the ajax, I could not get anything.

```
$.ajax({
   url:'http://192.168.1.5:8084/****/Servlet',
   data: ajaxdata,
   type:'GET',
   dataType:'text/html',
   //contentType: "text/html",
   success:function(json) { }
});
```

So any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

If you have control over the servlet, set the [HTTP `Access-Control`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTTP_access_control) headers. This way you can control from the server side on whether the client who has fired the XMLHttpRequest is allowed to process the response. Any recent (and decent) webbrowser will take action accordingly.

Here's an example:

```
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*"); // Everone may process the response.
response.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Methods", "GET"); // Commaseparated string of allowed request methods.
```

An alternative is [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#JSONP), see also [this article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/wa-aj-jsonp1/).

Answer (score 0):

!jigsaw

this is called same origin policy problem in ajax, It will work if both are on the same server.

read this link , its very nice

[Ways to circumvent the same-origin policy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3076414/ways-to-circumvent-the-same-origin-policy)

```
http://www.petefreitag.com/item/703.cfm
```

search in stack over flow you will get lot of answers

Comment: Oh. thanks a lot. Do I have to use real webservice instead of servlet to achieve things like this? For example, you can get some data from a webservice URL

Comment: I understand. it's about ajax not service. Ajax has this "same origin" policy. But I can still access a servlet to get some data I need.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use AJAX to send a request to a different site.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are making cross-domain ajax. Browsers tend to forbid this, because it is a security problem.

See [here](http://usejquery.com/posts/9/the-jquery-cross-domain-ajax-guide) and [here](http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/04/cross-domain-ajax-querying-with-jquery.html).

(Obviously, you will not have any problems when they are on the same server)